# multiple Arraylist inside one

Tags: android, database, arraylist, expandablelistview

i'm using a custom expandable listview in my app and i`m stopped in one issue. I'm trying to insert in each group all the results from the query and for that i'm using 2 queries..one for the parent and another for the child.

So...the result from parent query returns a String[] with the values that i put normally on parent group list.

When i try to query the itens for the child..i use the parent result as parameter for get the values. The problem i`m having is that only the last item was list on the child row is showed.

I`m trying to put each result from String[parent number] on a Arraylist that i respective put on his parent Array...but only the last query was showed in all the parent group.

What i think is the queries are overwrite the previous one and adding this one instead of adding all. Searching on some topic i found something like Multidimensional array..is that what i have to use?

this is the part of the code that i stopped

```
//String[] with the result from the parent query 
String[] teste = consulta.NomeArtista(busca);
//custom array for parent
ArrayList<ItemExpandable> ArrayItem = new ArrayList<ItemExpandable>();
    //custom array for child
    ArrayList<DataAdapter.ItemLista> ArraySubItem = null;
    //using the parent size  for create all the parent group
    for (int i = 0; i < teste.length; i++) {
    //Create a array with all the field belong to parent 
        ArraySubItem = consulta.consultaArtista(teste[i]);
        ItemExpandable itens = new ItemExpandable();
        itens.setTitle(teste[i]);
        itens.setArrayFilhos(ArraySubItem);
        Log.v(String.valueOf(ArraySubItem),"2");
        ArrayItem.add(itens);
    }
    //My custom ExpListview with the 2 arraylist
    listagem.setAdapter(new CustomBaseAdapter(artista.this.getActivity(), ArrayItem, ArraySubItem));
```

Comment: Maybe this would help you 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357411/connect-multiple-arraylist-to-one-single-array-list